# jquery remove() - resulting text() still contains removed element

Tags: jquery

I'm missing something with jQuery remove().
My `<label>`s contain extraneous text which I want removing:

```
<label>
  <span class="removeme">Horrible Text</span>
  Nice Text
</label>

$("label").remove(".removeme").text()
```

The result still shows "Horrible Text Nice Text" - what gives? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dancl/wwed4zpq/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do this you need to use `.find()` , `.end()`

```js
$("div").html($("label").find(".removeme").remove().end().text());
```

```css
label {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  <span class="removeme">Horrible Text</span>
  Nice Text
</label>

<div>Result</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen `end()` before

Answer (score 0):

[`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) returns the removed element(s), if any, so `text()` will still work even though it's no longer in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

`$("label").text('')`

This code will replace the text of your label with an empty string, meaning it will effectively delete all the text inside. `.remove()` actually deletes the whole element that you specify. If all you want to do is empty the text, then use my suggestion.